# How do I make dvd::rip not freeze halfway through a DVD?

Tags: dvd, media, dvd-backup

When trying to rip a DVD, it freezes after 30 minutes.
[image]
When I try to transcode a small part of the dvd, 
[image]
I get this error.
[image]

Comment: By the way, what Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: Happy July 4th!

Comment: Also take a look at this: [dvd::rip](http://www.exit1.org/dvdrip/doc/faq.cipp#faq16)

Comment: oneiric  Also, I'm pretty sure I've done enough de-css stuff to allow me to rip my encrypted dvds.

Comment: The latest DVD copy protections aren't done with CSS but with bad sectors on the DVD that make ripping programs crash.

Answer (score 0):

That might be a bug in the software. Have you tried using a different application? I use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) and have only had good experiences so far. (They don't have a dev for 12.04 yet, but the 11.10 version works perfectly on 12.04.)

If your DVD is copy protected Handbrake will most likely also fail. To still make a copy of your DVD you could try [this](http://www.cmdln.org/2010/01/22/backing-up-disney-dvds/) slightly more complicated method.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nicer if you write the name of the app that you are using.

Anyway use Handbrake, this application is modern and supports a much more efficient and scalable codec, Handbrake also support the old AVI container for some legacy use like ripping a file for playing it in your video player that only accept AVI files.

Comment: The name of the app I'm using is dvdrip.  Is dvd::rip something different?